# Generating token to access google account

Tags: android, google-api, android-studio, google-tasks

I've a problem with generating a second token in my application. I registered 2 accounts on my phone. When I use the first account token is generating, but when I choose the second token isn't generated.
My code:

```
accountManager.getAuthTokenByFeatures("com.google", "Manage your tasks", null, this,
                             Bundle.EMPTY, Bundle.EMPTY, new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {
                                @Override
                                public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> bundleAccountManagerFuture) {
                                    try {
                                        String token = bundleAccountManagerFuture.getResult()
                                                .getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
                                        Log.e("token", token);
                                    } catch (AuthenticatorException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    } catch (OperationCanceledException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            }, null);
```

I get the following errors:

> **android.accounts.AuthenticatorException: Unknown
>   android.accounts.AccountManager.convertErrorToException(AccountManager.java:1726)
>   android.accounts.AccountManager.access$400(AccountManager.java:144)
>   android.accounts.AccountManager$AmsTask$Response.onError(AccountManager.java:1572)
>   android.accounts.IAccountManagerResponse$Stub.onTransact(IAccountManagerResponse.java:69)
>   android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:407)
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)**

Comment: u found any solution?

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter in `getAuthTokenByFeatures` should be a valid scope (eg: `oauth2:https://gdata.youtube.com`)